# Should I use \r or \n for explode()ing the contents of a file in PHP?

Tags: php, string, explode

I'm creating a function which can accept a string which is either retrieved through `file_get_contents()` on a local text file, or something fetched from a url such as `http://site.com/338383.txt`.

The file will be a tab seperated file, with each item in the file being on its own line. Is it better to use `\n` or `\r` to `explode()` the string and get an array of each line?

I've noticed that in some cases `\n` doesn't work. I'd like a consistent way which works all the time. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [file()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to get the contents of the file as array with individual lines.

Answer (score 2):

As [duckyflip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7370/duckyflip) points out, you can use the [file()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function to get an array of file lines.  However, if you still need to explode (for an unknown reason), you should use the PHP constant `PHP_EOL` instead of '\n' as this is cross-platform compliant.

Comment: But couldn't you still be reading a file written on a different platform? So in that case PHP_EOL on the server would not necessarily correspond to that in the file?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crlf) is defined differently for different "text/plain" encodings and platforms. The quick-and-dirty solution would probably be to use split and the regular expression "\r\n|\r|\n", however, it may break on some unicode files and it has no sense of "context". I.e. if you have a file where LF (\n) is used as a EOL marker, and there's some CRs there which should have been preserved, the CRs will be split on as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_split ()](http://php.net/preg-split) to explode by /\n\r|\n|\r/, and then [trim ()](http://php.net/trim) each item to make sure no trailing whitespace is remaining (if it’s appropriate).